# How can i get the add using mopub sdk

Tags: iphone

Iam doing one application.In that my requirment is using mopub sdk i need to get the advertisment and display that one.But main problem is i dont want to get the advertisment from mopub server.I need to use my own server address.So please tell me how can change the server address and may i need to change anything.

Comment: If you dont want to use its server then why do want to implement mopub's SDK?

Comment: Just i get the add from my server and use the other benfits from Mopub sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible. If you want to use your server. Then create a webview in your application with same size of ads at bottom, load it from your server and refresh it  at every 10-15 seconds interval.

Comment: But if iuse web view then i didin't get the benefits from MOPUB sdk.

Comment: Yea, But you cannot use your server with MOPUB SDK. you can choose ads provided by  MOPUB

Comment: If u don't mine please give me 100% proof.Because i need to explain to my TL